# vba strings replacing

Tags: string, vbscript

OK Starting all over again and hopefully a bit more straight forward.

```
Var = 24
string = "var"

x = string
```

This results in

x = "var"  **NOT** x = 24

Is it possible to retrieve the value of **var**, by using the string stored in **string**

Thank you

Aaron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you are able to do that. As a solution you can use a collection to mimic this behaviour:

```
Sub TestCollection()
  Dim Values As New Collection

  Values.Add "24", "Var"
  Values.Add "Alexander", "Name"

  MsgBox Values("Var") & " " & Values("Name")
End Sub
```

Comment: HI please see my edit above so explain a bit more what i need.

Comment: I think what also might explain it better is how once I have pulled out the "port" string from the whole string, do i use that to find the associated value.

Comment: Exactly what I need, in fact at about 1am this morning a friend also suggest the same idea. Still haven't tested it yet, but can't believe I didnt think of this. I have used discretionary's  in C#  so the same thing and perfect for what I want. Thank you so much for that answer and sticking with it. Aaron